# protractor browser error log not complete

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I want to make sure my angular application does not log any errors in the console when loading the page where the application is located.

For that I use protractor and so far I have the following test:

spec.js:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function () {


    it('should show all logs', function () {

        browser.get('http://localhost:9050/#/10');

        browser.sleep(20000)

        browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserLogs) {

            console.log(browserLogs)

            browserLogs.forEach(function (log) {
                console.log("-------------------");
                console.log(log.message);
                if (log.level.value > 900) {
                    throw log.message;
                }
            });
        });


    });
});
```

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose: true,
        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,
        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace: true,
        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'loggingPrefs' : {"driver": "ALL", "server": "ALL", "browser": "ALL"}
    },


};
```

when I look at the terminal output I get only the first element of the logs. However if I open the console in chrome and look at the logs myself there are more error and warning logs but they are not part of the terminal output. How is this possible, what did I miss ?

Comment: What are the levels of logs that you get in chrome? try changing the log level to 800 - `if (log.level.value >= 800)` as most of the log levels are either 800 or 900

Comment: Weird, your code works fine for me, can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(log))` ?

Comment: @GirishSortur I added my config for the tests. Changing the loggingPrefs made it better but the log is still not complete. Firefox behaves similarly

Comment: Did you change the log levels as i said above and see if it prints all of them?

Comment: if you mean by 'changing log level' changing the line of code where I ask for a log message that has a level more than 900, then yes but it doesn't make a difference and also I dump the whole log beforehand anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into the same issue, the console errors reported by protractor were not the same as the errors I saw when opening a page in a browser manually. Here is how I solved my problem, I used the `navigate()` method instead of `get()`. They should be the same but at least in my case they do produce different results in the browser console.

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function () {

    it('should show all logs', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:9050/#/10');

        // Clear console log
        browser.manage().logs().get('browser');

        // Load the page again, now with the navigate() method
        browser.navigate().to('http://localhost:9050/#/10');

        browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserLogs) {

            console.log(browserLogs);

            browserLogs.forEach(function (log) {
                console.log("-------------------");
                console.log(log.message);
                if (log.level.value > 900) {
                    throw log.message;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This only helps when the error occurs during page load. What if it happens after a lot of actions on the page itself?